# How to enable/disable rows of textbox that enable rows are textbox which I selected with checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a table of list student, I want to insert value of students into database. But this table have multiple checkbox, if I choose the checkbox of the table, the checkbox must be enable. I want to insert the value of student which the checkbox are enable. I used codeigniter to build this web.

this is my source

```
<?php $this->load->view("asisten/v_header");?>
<?php $this->load->view("asisten/v_top_menu");?>
<?php $this->load->view("asisten/v_sidebar");?>

<div class="content">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="page-title">Form Input Nilai Praktikum</h1>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Nim</th>
                <th>Nama Praktikan</th>
                <th>Nilai 1</th>
                <th>Nilai 2</th>
                <th>Nilai 3</th>
                <th>Nilai 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if($list_praktikan->num_rows()>0)
                {
                $no=$off+1;
                foreach($list_praktikan->result()as $data):
                ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td><?php echo $no;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->nim;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->nama;?></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="input-mini" name="id_nilai1"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="input-mini" name="id_nilai2"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="input-mini" name="id_nilai3"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="input-mini" name="id_nilai4"/></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        $no++;
        endforeach;
            }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<?php $this->load->view("asisten/v_footer");?>
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5kcKP/1/

Answer (score -1):

I think

```
<input type="checkbox" id="name<?php $i;?>" onclick="encChbox(<?php echo $i;?>)" value="">
```

$i means increment a variable for identify the checkbox. with the help of the function parameter we can get the value of that checkbox.

encChbox is a function.  we can write the process in this function. insert or other process .  This is one idea with the help of the idea you can....

Comment: Great Idea, coz if I want to insert into database, I can use this ID. Thank bro.